# Java HttpsServer - Forcing TLSv1.1

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate

I am running Java 8 and using `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer` to create a HTTPS server. I have a working implementation using a trusted CA signed EC certificate in a Java KeyStore.

I have been looking at how I could restrict what Ciphers and Protocols the server could support (similar to Apache using "SSLProtocol" and "SSLCipherSuite" in the configuration) - mainly to enforce a higher level of security by disabling the use of SHA-1.

No one should really be forcing TLSv1.1 over 1.2, but I am just doing this to prove a point that the following configuration works:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
// Load KeyStore into "ks"

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, jksPassword.toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init(ks);

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

HttpsServer hsS = HttpsServer.create(sBind, 0);
hsS.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sc) {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpsParameters p) {
    try {
      SSLContext c = getSSLContext();
      SSLEngine e = c.createSSLEngine();

      p.setNeedClientAuth(false);
      p.setProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.1" });
      p.setCipherSuites(e.getEnabledCipherSuites());
      p.setSSLParameters(c.getDefaultSSLParameters());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
```

Even though I use `setProtocols()` to only accept "TLSv1.1", this doesn't seem to stop "TLSv1.2" connections and everything from Chrome to IE still uses "TLSv1.2". If I disable the use of "TLSv1.2" and "TLSv1.1" in IE and just leave "TLSv1.0" enabled then it will still work and negotiate "TLSv1.0". The `setProtocols()` method doesn't seem to do anything!?!

If I got this working then I was going to modify the list of Ciphers using `setCipherSuites()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak it by updating `jre/lib/security/java.security` file. Look for an entry like below and tweak.

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.2, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, \
EC keySize < 224
```

Comment: That is good, but am I missing the point of `setProtocols()` and `setCipherSuites()` to be able to do this programmatically? I might not necessarily want to (or have access to) change it globally on the whole server.